# Twitter like network using graph theroy and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, graph-theory

My application consists of users posting content and interacting with each others. It's a twitter like containing a news feed populated from the persons they follow.

I would like to display the posts from the direct followers, and optionally going deeper (followers of followers, etc...).

**What king of implementation, using MongoDB, would you suggest ?**

It seems like a good candidate for graphs, using the `graphLookup` aggregation stage. I thought about using 3 collections :

- `users` : containing users name, phone number, etc...
- `relationships` : this collection would contains every user's relationships
- `posts` : containing posts

The idea is to have one collection modelling relationships (`relationships`), and use it to select any other content from a person's network. In the example it's about posts, but some more content could be added in the future (coming from other collections). The goal is to keep separated the relationships from the other collections.

I'm looking for an efficient way to do this king of queries using MongoDB.

Comment: what do you mean by "but some more content could be added in the future, coming from other collections." ?

Comment: In addition to posts,  we could imagine have ads for example. I would like to keep the relationships only in one collection and benefit from it into the other collections.